# How to write workbook name in cell using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write an excel workbook name (the current one) in a cell using an excel macro.

I've tried to use

```
"=RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",R[-9]C[1]),LEN(CELL(""filename"",R[-9]C[1]))-SEARCH(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-9]C[1])))"
```

and it seems to be buggy, I would like to use the

`ActiveWorkbook` method.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this gets the worksheet, is there a way to get the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write the `ActiveWorbook.Name` to the cell, e.g.:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
```